# how to live stream video from raspberry pi to remote device which is from a different network?

Tags: python, image-processing, live-streaming, pi

I am working on a raspberry pi project about object detection. I want the pi to live stream send video to my remote laptop which is on a different network. I have to give the live stream video from the pi as input to the image processing code.

Comment: There are many ways of doing this... basic sockets, zeroMQ sockets, vlc, ffmpeg, Redis. You would need to be more specific about your latency and bandwidth requirements and availability, whether you tolerate lower colour accuracy or even greyscale, what image size and frame rate you need. You also need to give some indication of the languages/technologies you are able to use, what code you have tried and what is the current stumbling block. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use VLC to host the video livestream. I did a port forward in the router so it can be watched from everywhere. Maybe this video and tutorial could help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JjPsW-7FUng
https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-Raspberry-Pi-Webcam-Server-and-Stream-/

Comment: Thanks for helping. Is there any way that i can use this streaming video as input to my object detection program in my laptop?The program is python and uses tensorflow.

Comment: @SowmyaBhatt I'm not familiar with using tensorflow.